# Python - Dynamic 'navigation menu' based on entries in Database

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm wondering how I can dynamically generate options in a navigation menu based on values from a table in my database.

I have some records in a database table. For each I would like to create a Menu Item for based on a specific field. 
i.e.

```
TABLE: pages, 
id int, 
page_name varchar(255), 
page_info varchar (255);
```

So based on how many **page_name** are in table 'pages' i want to create a menu item/button for. The obvious reason i would want this is so that if and when I create a new entry into my database, it will automatically appear as an option on my menu. (Side note: I plan to change the content 'page_info'  of div's based on what menu item is selected)

I know that this could be quite simply achieved in PHP but How could this possibly be achieved in Python?

Answer (score -1):

This is a really open-ended question which is hard to give you a specific answer.  However, if I was making something like this I would use a simple Flask application with pyodbc to query whatever database you are pulling the data from.  From there I would use a jinja template to build the actual html with our database results.

[Pyodbc Docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki)

[Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)

[Jinja2 Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/)

Comment: This is a very open-ended answer, which has no specific information. If I wanted the Python Docs i could have googled them!.

Comment: @sid, StackOverflow is not the place to just have people write code for you.  If you can show us the code that you have written and the steps that you have taken than we can be able to help you a little more effectively.

Comment: I'm well aware that StackOverflow is not a code writing service, I have not requested code to be written to me. My question i quite comprehensive and I have kept it simple as I don't want to put too much information.  I'm only requesting specific guidance, not for you to put the Python manual up. FYI i wasnt the one who voted your answer down...